# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType when run in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting the following error when I run 'deploy application' in eclipse with TomEE 1.7.3. The same application gets deployed successfully when I deploy it in an external TomEE 1.7.3.

- Eclipse Mars (4.5.0)
- Jdk 1.8

Why would this be happening?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
    at com.dassault_systemes.platform.restServices.MediaProviderJSON.<clinit>(MediaProviderJSON.java:32)
    at com.dassault_systemes.platform.restServices.JsonTypeConvertFilter.<clinit>(JsonTypeConvertFilter.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where ever `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType` is coming from within Eclipse is not there when you deploy to TomEE. Is `com.dassault_systemes.platform.restServices.MediaProviderJSON` a class you're compiling from source or one that you're just using? Where does the "deploy application" functionality come from?

Comment: no i mean when i am trying to deploy my application in eclipse while starting tomcat i am getting that error , however if i run it in external tomcat it works fine ..

Comment: Have you checked the version of JSR-311 library is loaded (0.9 version of the jsr311-api jar is obsolete) in the server.if you have not added `jersey-core jar` as a runtime dependency then please add it.Check if you have all the required jar.